# Add delineators to a string in-place

Tags: c

Someone posed this challenge to me awhile back, and I've been running it through my mind.  I've tried a couple of different approaches but they've proved incorrect.

What I want to do is, given some string (eg. abcdefghijkl), size multiple of 4, I want to place a delineator (for example, '-') every four characters.  This seems easy at first, but the constraint is it has to be done in place (no allocating new memory and copying from the input to the output.)

I want to do this in C.  I don't necessarily expect a cook-book "here's how you do it" answer, but some conceptual direction would be nice.

Edit:  I think the expectation is, there are unused bytes allocated at the end of the input string, sufficient in number to allow for the delineators.

Comment: How can you expect do to without allocating the memory for the additional `-` characters? Or there is already place at the end of the characters?

Comment: Conceptually you do need some new memory. Theoretically the string is being viewed as a `char*` allowing `char` modification, but we need to insert `-` so there will be some new memory needed.

Comment: @Matteo (and dylan), that wasn't specified but I added a note above that I hope addresses this

Comment: You can then move the characters beginning from the end (you will then not overwrite anything)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to calculate the shift before hand.

So given some character array ch do the following.

```
totalShift=strlen(ch)/4;
```

Then you know how many spaces to increment for a reverse loop over the character array like so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char bob[64];

    strncpy(bob,"helloSmith",sizeof("helloSmith"));
    int size=strlen(bob);
    int totalShift=size/4;
    int tmpCount=0;
    int i;
    bob[size+totalShift+1]='\0';
    for(i=size+totalShift;i>=4;i--){
        bob[i]=bob[i-totalShift-1];
        tmpCount++;
        if(tmpCount==4){
            i--;
            bob[i]='-';
            totalShift--;
            tmpCount=0;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n",bob);
    return 0;
}
```

This method basically moves your last character over to where you KNOW the string will eventually end since you can calculate this before hand. From there you are shifting back into the string and shifting the characters the correct amount as needed.

I may have some fundamental logic error there but I think you can get the core concept from here. I know it's typically considered "dangerous" to change your increment inside the loop however it is required for this kind of logic and I think the problem inherenetly calls for it.

Edit:
Changed sizeof to strlen since sizeof will return size of allocated memory which would be very bad. Also I moved the end of the loop to be at 4 because the last chunk of memmory should not be shifted. Also I just pasted some code I wrote that worked.

Second Edit:
As a comment below pointed out this method does put the -'s from right to left which may be a bit weird. Below I'll post a second set of code which works left to right. You can compare the differences for yourself.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char bob[64];

    strncpy(bob,"abcdefg",sizeof("abcdefg"));
    int size=strlen(bob);
    int totalShift=(size/4)-1;
    int tmpCount=0;
    int i;
    int initCon=(size%4);
    int firstLoop=1;
    bob[size+totalShift+1]='\0';
    for(i=size+totalShift;i>=4;i--){
        bob[i]=bob[i-totalShift-1];
        tmpCount++;
        if(firstLoop&&tmpCount==initCon){
            firstLoop=0;
            tmpCount=0;
            i--;
            bob[i]='-';
            totalShift--;
        }
        if(tmpCount==4){
            i--;
            bob[i]='-';
            totalShift--;
            tmpCount=0;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n",bob);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good code example, but there's one small thing: This adds a hyphen every 4 characters counting from the end. The question doesn't state this explicitly, but wouldn't it be more natural to base the place of the hyphens on the beginning? There's also something wrong in the first chunk, depending on your input length.

Comment: ... Curse you @MOehm haha. Ummmm it would be more "natural" if the hypens were inserted from there but I believe the adjust is pretty easy. For those interested what I would suggest is keeping the logic the same but doing a modulus of the TotalShift calculation, from there you know how deep the first place/last in string '-' should go. Then go back to using tmpCount. Basically just putting an initial condition in the String.

Comment: Yes, but that also trips your logic of looping until `i >= 4`. Try splitting `"abcdef"` or `"abcdefg"`.

Comment: Put a second set of code that works for left to right. The logic works the same just need to change the totalShift count and put an initial condition in.